# Removing AdWords conversion making Analytics disappear

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am planning to remove AdWords conversion tracking from a page and when I delete the code below it is making Analytics code disappear as well. Any idea why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 111111111;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "Ar2XYX79jwNMgv10K2AB";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/111111111/?value=0&amp;label=Ar2XYX79jwNMgv10K2AB&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: :) corrected the typo

Comment: Any one got any idea?

Comment: Can you clarify "making Analytics code disappear" please?